# Get file name from URL folder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, url

How to get all file names from folder url? Below code returns null.

```
path = @"http://localhost/urlFolder/images/";

NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
```

Comment: please read apple guide line documents, please RND about your stuff then ask question, please be clear about your question and ask in details..

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried another method of `NSFileManager`

```
- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:(NSURL *)url includingPropertiesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions)mask error:(NSError **)error
```

You can use `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error:` instead of `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`

Try it. Happy Coding. :)